# Moving Right One Cell

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I'm trying to move one cell to the right in a macro.

```
Range("C5").Select  <-- a formula that needs to be copied
Selection.Copy
Range("B5").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.Paste
```

SendKeys does not appear to be the answer to this issue as it puts a TAB or RIGHT arrow directly into the next line of macro code, emulating keyboard strokes only. Is there another way to move my cell selection to the right from the end of Bn to Cn, where n is unknown?

Comment: Sendkeys is never the solution as it opens a huge can of worms where anything can go wrong.  Look at Range.Offset https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel

Comment: @JeanRostan did you intend to put a `+1` in there?

Comment: Do you want to move the content of a cell , to the cell right next to it ? Your code is kinda messy. If I understand correctly, that would be simply to get active cell, then add +1 to the column. Use `cellA = ActiveCell` and then `cellRight = Cells(cellA.Row,cellA.Column+1)` and `cellRight.Value=cellA.Value` thanks@ashleedawg

Comment: Thank you Sorceri. This is exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 6):

To reference one cell to the right of the active cell:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
```

To return the **address** of the cell one to the right:

```
MsgBox ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address
```

To move the **selection** once cell to the right:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
```

---

Code from your answer but tidied up:

```
Range("C5").Copy
Range("B5").End(xlDown).Offset(columnoffset:=1).Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
```

It doesn't really *do* anything.  It copies but doesn't paste.

Answer (score 3):

your code can boil down to:

```
range("C5").Copy range("B5").End(xlDown).Offset(columnoffset:=1)
```

or, if you only need to paste values:

```
range("B5").End(xlDown).Offset(columnoffset:=1).value = range("C5").value
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are after something like the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCellColC As Range

' find last row with data in column "B"
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Set LastCellColC = Range("B" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1)

' if you realy need to use Select
LastCellColC.Select
```

---

I think this is what you are really after, copying the formula from "C5" till the last cell in Column "C" (according to the last row with data in column "B")

```
Dim LastRow As Long

' find last row with data in column "B"
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

' copying the formula from "C5" all the way to the last cell
Range("C5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C5:C" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the fix to my issue.

```
Range("C5").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B5").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(columnoffset:=1).Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
```

Comment: Your question didn't say anything about copying