# Excel VBA - Do While Loop - Date in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, while-loop

I want to increase the settlement date which is *(assigned to cell N13)* until the network days (assigned to cell P11) reaches 3.

Network days counts the number of weekdays between two dates excluding holidays. However, I added a range of holidays to it.

```
Sub Settlement_Date()

Do While Cells(16, 12) < 3
    
    Cells(14,11)
    
Loop
```

[image: Excel sheet screenshot]

Comment: Currently at this stage of the code

Sub Settlement_Date()

Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value < 3

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
    
Loop

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to increase `Cells(14,11)` within the loop, change that line to

```vba
Cells(14,11) = Cells(14,11) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it myself but got snippets in some of the post I found here

```
Sub Settlement_Date()

Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value < 3 

    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
    
Loop

End Sub
```

[Moving Right One Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676418/moving-right-one-cell)
[Add one day to date in cells using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156271/add-one-day-to-date-in-cells-using-vba)